# Best way to run a background task with timer

Tags: c#, wpf, begininvoke

The following code run a task which check, each 5 seconds, the status of a database. I had to use the BeginInvoke but I'm not sure is the best way to do:

```
public btnDatabaseStatus()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        Global.LM.SetTraduzioniWindow(this);                        
    Init();

    DispatcherOperation dbStatDispatcher = null;
    try
    {
        dbStatDispatcher = App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
        {
            Timer timer = new Timer(5000);
            timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (dbStatDispatcher != null) dbStatDispatcher.Abort();
    }
}

private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (App.Current!=null) App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { IsDbConnected = Dbs[0].IsConnected; }));
}

private void Init()
{
    Dbs = null;
    Dbs = Global.DBM.DB.Values.Where(d => d.IsExternalDB).ToList();
    lstvDatabase.ItemsSource = Dbs;
}
```

I'm afraid concerning the closing of main application as sometimes the Dispatcher is null. Any hints to improve the code?

Comment: What kind of app is this? If the code works, and you want to get a thorough review of your code, you *might* be better off on [codereview.se], but you should read their [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) thoroughly before posting there.

Comment: `App?.Current?.Dispatcher?.BeginInvoke` boom.

Comment: take a look at System.Threading.Timer.dll https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Heretic Monkey is a wpf application. Anyway thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget about `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` and `System.Threading.Timer`.

Use a WPF DispatcherTimer:

```
public btnDatabaseStatus()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) };
    timer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
    timer.Start();
}

private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IsDbConnected = Dbs[0].IsConnected;
}
```

Or shorter:

```
public btnDatabaseStatus()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) };
    timer.Tick += (s, e) => IsDbConnected = Dbs[0].IsConnected;
    timer.Start();
}
```

---

If the Tick handler is supposed to do some long-running task, you may declare it async:

```
private async void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await SomeLongRunningMethod();

    // probably update UI after await
}
```